# Condicionantes en consulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actualmente tengo una serie de querys que buscar la informacion de un cliente, tengo 2 tablas las cuales son **Clients** y **Identity** , en la primer tabla se guarda toda la informacion del cliente en la segunda los documentos (identidad, pasaporte etc..) la cosa es que en algunos casos la identificacion no sale en la tabla **Clients** y sale en la tabla **Identity**, entonces para realizar un filtro en el query y buscar al cliente por numero de identificacion he realizado lo siguiente

```
DECLARE @Identidad VARCHAR(25)='0801199445212' 

SELECT DISTINCT
cc.ClientId,
cc.NombreCliente,
cc.Identidad,
id.DocNum
FROM dbo.Clients cc

OUTER APPLY(
SELECT TOP 1 id.DocNum
FROM dbo.IdentityDocs id
WHERE id.ClientId=cc.ClientId 
)id
WHERE (cc.Identidad=@Identidad OR id.DocNum=@Identidad)
```

En donde en el WHERE filtro si no encuentra la identidad en una tabla busque en la otra, solo que veo que a veces se tarda un poco, entonces mi pregunta es si esto es eficiente? hay alguna otra forma mas eficiente de realizar este tipo de busquedas? estoy usando mal el OR

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon la estructura de tus tablas, y especifica que campos quieres mostrar

Comment: Tienes que tener en cuenta que estas haciendo una consulta en otra tabla para validar si esta o no, este proceso puede que no sea el mas optimo pero quizas si es el mas facil de manejar, otra seria que indexaras el campo para que la consulta fuera un poco mas rapida, pero siguiendo el comentario de arriba deberias poner la estructura para hacernos la idea de masomenos que puede estar influyendo en tu consulta

Answer (score 0):

Tienes algunas cosas que pueden penalizar a la query, como por ejemplo `distinct`.

No obstante cuando estás buscando optimizar algo, es necesario saber la estructura de las tablas, los índices que tienes, el plan de ejecución que se está realizando, el volúmen de datos. No es tán simple como decir, esto se puede hacer más rápido.

Por otro lado, aunque el operador `apply` es simplemente genial (opinión personal), en determinados escenarios, puede penalizar su ejecución.

```
Create table dbo.Clients
         (
         ClientId      int
       , NombreCliente varchar(100)
       , Identidad     varchar(25)
       , DocNum        varchar(100)
         );

Create table dbo.IdentityDocs
             (
             ClientId int
           , DocNum   varchar(25)
             );
Go

Insert into dbo.Clients
(ClientId, NombreCliente, Identidad, DocNum)
Values
(1,'Juan','0801199445214','a'),
(2,'Ana','0801199445212','b'),
(3,'Bea','0801199445213','c');
Insert into dbo.IdentityDocs
(ClientId, DocNum)
values
(2, '0801199445212'),
(2, '0801199445220'),
(2, '0801199445221'),
(3, '0801199445213');
GO
```

Una consulta que te puede ir algo mejor, según lo que pareces comentar, de la permanencia de la info en las dos tablas:

```
DECLARE @Identidad VARCHAR(25)='0801199445214' 

SELECT top(1)
cc.ClientId,
cc.NombreCliente,
cc.Identidad,
id.DocNum
FROM dbo.Clients cc Left join IdentityDocs id on cc.ClientId = id.ClientId
WHERE coalesce(cc.Identidad,id.DocNum) = @Identidad;
```

Pero de cualquier manera, tal cual está, tiene que leer las dos tablas completas para poder extraer la información.

[image: Result]

El plan de ejecución.

[image: plan1]

Si buscas por el documento 12.

```
DECLARE @Identidad VARCHAR(25)='0801199445212' 

SELECT top(1)
cc.ClientId,
cc.NombreCliente,
cc.Identidad,
id.DocNum
FROM dbo.Clients cc Left join IdentityDocs id on cc.ClientId = id.ClientId
WHERE coalesce(cc.Identidad,id.DocNum) = @Identidad;
```

[image: Result2]